# Relaxing color setting while working with Latex?

Tags: color

This may seem an off topic question for this site but I'm a professional typesetter, working many hours per day, with emacs and okular with a setting as in the screenshot:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any package that provides tools to improve the typesetting experience. E.g. changing the background color for a more comfortable reading as in my next example.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagecolor[HTML]{FFE7BA}
\color[HTML]{373D3F}
```

[image]

Note that it is just a test and I'd need to change the default color of hyperlinks to make it more comfortable.

I'd really appreciate every kind of help.

**Note.** I changed the text of my answer to make it less generic and opinion-based. If this is not enough, please let me know if there is a place in where it is allowed to ask this kind of help.

Comment: #e4ede9 as a background is somewhat like eye-ease paper.

Comment: OT, but I like [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color schemes.

Comment: @Thérèse It looks nice and comfortable.  I'll try it for a while. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, you can change the paper color in `okular` without changinf the document source. It's in accesibility -> change colors settings.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out to pass the options by command line (I made a tweak to the emacs's latex-compiling command), without changing the document source.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi perhaps you could post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @cmhughes Do you mean my emacs tweak?